# Error: connect ETIMEDOUT Using node.js to download zip

Tags: node.js, proxy, timeout

I am using node.js to download a zip folder from github's server. For some reason the code below works on any other network except for at work. Not sure it's a proxy or firewall issue slowing down the request causing a timeout.

```
var https   = require('https');
var fs      = require('fs');
var options = {
    hostname  : 'codeload.github.com',
    port      : 443,
    path      : '/wet-boew/wet-boew/zip/master',
    method    : 'GET'
};

var file = fs.createWriteStream("test_folder/master.zip");

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    console.log("headers: ", res.headers);
    res.on('data', function(d) {
        file.write(d);
    });
});
req.end();

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error(e);
});
```

This is the full error that is generated when running the above code on the network:

{ [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT] code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect' }

any work around ideas or help is appreciated, thanks!